# Casting conversion of int to int32

Tags: sql, go

I am working on pulling in rows from the Db and storing the results in a Slice/Array

I need to calculate the totalRecords & totalPages.

```
pseudoCode :: 
perPage int32 := ( some number ) 
totalRecords := len(array)
totalPages := perPage/totalRecords
```

I keep getting this error.

```
terminal::
`invalid operation: perPage / totalRecords (mismatched types int32 and int)`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`len(array)` returns an `int` convert it to an int32 int32(len(array)) or convert perPage to an `int`

Comment: Thank you. New to Golang. Thumbs Up!